# How to describe a future event?

Tags: clauses, future-tense, future-time

For example,

I am working in an office right now.
Today, I will arrive home on 6 pm, then I will call my mom immediately.

Please help me to correct the following sentences.
Please point out which one is right or wrong.

1. When I arrives home, I will call my mom.
2. When I arrived home, I will call my mom.
3. On the heels of arriving home, I will call my mom.
4. After arriving home, I will call my mom.

Please also choose the best one.

Comment: You can also write *mum* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/mum_1?q=mum

Answer (score 2):

1.) use arrive instead of arrives "When I arrive home, I will call my mom"

2.) arrived is past tense so it should be "When I arrive home, I will call my mom" or "When I arrived home, I called my mom"

3.) I think it's fine grammatically, but the phrase "on the heals of" seems awkward in this sentence

4.) This one is fine

I think #1 (corrected to "When I arrive home, I will call my mom") is the best, but #4 is good too.

Comment: I would not use #4 because I feel like #4 is a repeat of your #1. That is, I would not use "After", I would use "When" and so it would just be the same as your revised #1.

Answer (score 1):

I am working in an office right now. Today, I will arrive home **AT** 6 pm, then I will call my mom immediately.

Future event:

> When I **arrive** home, I will call my mom.

Past event:

> When I arrived home, I **called** my mom.

Number 4 is also correct, but less commonly used.